Subsets of rational numbers with the additive properties: $(A-A)\cap (B-B)=\{ 0\}$ and $(A-A)+B=\mathbb{Q}$
We are looking for subsets $A$ of rational numbers such that the following conditions:
(1) $(A-A)\cap (B-B)=\{ 0\}$
(2) $(A-A)+B=\mathbb{Q}$
are satisfied for at least two subsets $B=B_1,B_2$ with distinct sizes one of which is finite and another one is infinite (i.e., there are two solutions $B_1$ and $B_2$ for the above system of equations such that $|B_1|< \aleph_0$, $|B_2|=\aleph_0$).
Note that $A-A=\{ a-\alpha:a,\alpha\in A\}$, $A+B=\{a+b:a\in A,b\in B\}$, and
(a) for every $\emptyset\neq A\subseteq \mathbb{Q}$, there are always infinitely many subsets $B$ that satisfy (1) and (2).
(b) the condition (1) holds if and only if the summation $A+B$ is direct (i.e., the representation of each $x\in A+B$ as $x=a+b$, $a\in A$, $b\in B$ is unique).
(c) if $A$ is fixed and $B_0$ is a maximal subset satisfying (1), then $B_0$ satisfies both (1) and (2).
(d)  $A$ (and $A-A$) must not be an additive subgroup of $(\mathbb{Q},+)$. For if $A\leq \mathbb{Q}$, then $B$ satisfies the conditions if and only if $B$ is a transversal of $A$ in $\mathbb{Q}$.
(e) a similar problem in $\mathbb{Z}$ (for finite cases) has the desired solution, e.g., if $A:=\{n^2: n\in \mathbb{Z}_+\}=\{1,4,9,\cdots\}$, $B=B_1:=\{-1,0,1\}$, and $B=B_2:=\{-4,-2,0,2\}$, then
$(A-A)\cap (B-B)=\{ 0\}$ and $(A-A)+B=\mathbb{Z}$.
(f) one can find more information in this, this, this and this.
Important remark. If there is any example of such subset $A$, then $A$ must be a generating set of $(\mathbb{Q},+)$, and the associated subsets $B$ may be obtained from this algorithm (it contains an example of such $A$ with two associated subsets $B_1,B_2$ both are finite). Now, are there any?
Thanks in advance.

Is there a question?

Never mind, I got it; you're looking for examples . . .

Thanks for your comment. Please see the recently mentioned remark (I think it should be helpful).

does $B$ have to be finite?

No, both modes (finite and infinite) are possible.

So you are looking for at least one subset $A$ of rational numbers such that the required conditions are satisfied?

Yes. A subset $A$ and two associated subsets $B_1,B_2$ with the properties.
